# .xib file view create new instance

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a huge problem that I do not know how to solve:

I created a view in `myViewController.xib`. Besides the main view of this view controller there is another view, which is named `matchView`.

In my main view I have a table view which has a match list. I want to use `matchView` in this table view but when I call `addSubview:matchView` the most recent information fills this view.

How can I create a new instance of this view every time?

Thanks.

Edit: I solved my own problem , i have created another class which is matchViewController and then created it everytime in cellforrowatindexpath and used it as [cell addSubview:matchView].

thanks for your help anyways..

Answer (score 0):

You will have to dynamically create a matchView for each row in your table.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                       reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    UIView *matchView = [[[UIView alloc]init]autorelease];
    [matchView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, width_of_your_table, height_of_your_table_cell)];
    //add here, in your matchView whatever content you need to be displaied
    [cell addSubview:matchView];
    return cell;
}
```